# error "X may be used uninitialized in this function"

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I tried to read around this site to find answer but none of the posts quite answered my problem (which is probably easy one).

I have a struct of person's id

```
struct user_id {
    uint8_t birthday;
    uint8_t birthmonth;
    uint16_t birthyear;
};
struct user_id xxxxx;

xxxxx.birthday=2; xxxxx.birthmonth=2; xxxxx.birthyear=2017;
```

I have to access person's birth year and save it to pointer and later use it in that format.

```
uint16_t *year;
*year = xxxxx.birthyear;
```

When I try to save value to *year I get the error described in title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `year = &xxxxx.birthyear;`

Comment: When you dereference `year` you attempt to access the value the pointer is pointing to. The problem is that you haven't actually made it point anywhere yet.

Comment: OFC, how did I missed that :D thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*year = xxxxx.birthyear;
```

This line means that you are trying to dereference `year` which is not pointing to anything yet.

To make it point to `xxxxx.birthyear`, do this

```
year = &xxxxx.birthyear;
```